# dpkg-buildpackage error when builing Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, dpkg, dpkg-buildpackage

I'm trying to build Linux Kernel ffor Ubuntu 20.04 with GCC 9.3.0.

There are instructions out there https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

```
make -j $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
```

After long running compiling C source files process I got the error:

```
make[2]: *** [debian/rules:7: build-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1559: deb-pkg] Error 2
```

What this error could be about?

Comment: This is offtopic. Not really programming question. Our sister site about Ubuntu may be more relevant (link on top right icon). In any case, you miss the relevant errors. It should be few line earlier.

Comment: There are probably error messages further up the output. Since the make is building things in parallel (that is what the `-j` option specifies), those error messages will be mixed in with the normal build messages.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for pointing out where to look for the answer. It was due to wrong certificate config.

Comment: @SomeName Could elaborate a bit more on how to fix this issue?

Comment: @MadPhysicist This is not actually the root cause (at least in my case).  The core problem usually logged much earlier. To troubleshoot it you could try to redirect stdout into a separate file so you can see what stderr shows.

Comment: @SomeName Thanks! I resorted to just running it on one core. Then I was able to see the true error that previously stayed somewhere above in the logs.